# Calling multiple json api files using jquery and displaying in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a html page where I am calling 2 json files and using jquery to pull the data and then display in html page. It works with no problems with one json file but with 2 there is an issue.

I have created a fiddle because I was unsure what to leave out and what exactly was the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/rE2dD/

The fiddle is slightly different to my code due to having to separate html and javascipt for the fiddle.

The differences are I have the scripts within the `<body>` tag each above the corresponding html
E.g.

```
<body>
<script></script>
<h1 id=title></h1>
<script></script>
<h1 id=title></h1>
</body>
```

My javascipt, jquery knowledge it quite limited and I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Can't have repeating ID's

Comment: thanks @tymeJV Yes I understand that and I have tried that but it doesn't seem to work I was wondering is it something else I was missing.